# Android: how to create a separate actionbar within a navigation drawer?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I want to display a completely different actionbar that is within a navigation drawer. Here is an example from the app Flow:

[image: flow]

you can see that on the right is the app with a different actionbar than that of the navigation drawer's. How could something like this be replicated?

Comment: According to your screenshot, this component is not a navigation drawer but a Sliding menu (third party library). Then, I am not sure that the sliding menu contains a real action bar. I'm pretty sure that the layout looks like an action bar :)

Comment: So the developer of flow "faked" the actionbar? interesting